# flutter_tts in for loop reading only the last index (FLUTTER)

Tags: android, flutter, for-loop, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using the `flutter_tts` package for text to speech in my program.
So, I have a List(called **steps**) which is returned from an API and we get the steps list like this :

> [Heat a large skillet over medium heat; add rice and lentils. Cook and stir until toasted and fragrant, 3 to 4 minutes. Rinse., Place rice-lentil mixture, 1 tablespoon ghee, and salt in a rice cooker or pressure cooker; add water. Cook according to manufacturer's instructions until rice and lentils are tender and the consistency of a paste, 20 to 25 minutes. Stir and mash into a fine paste., Heat 1 tablespoon ghee in a skillet over medium-high heat. Add black pepper and cumin seeds; cook until seeds start to pop, 2 to 3 minutes. Stir cumin mixture into rice-lentil mixture., Tear curry leaves roughly and stir into rice-lentil mixture; stir in ginger. Season with salt., Heat remaining 1 tablespoon ghee in a skillet over medium-high heat; cook and stir cashews until toasted and fragrant, 2 to 4 minutes. Garnish rice-lentil mixture with toasted cashews.]

And when I use my for loop for indexing,
The for loop :

```
 for (var i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {
  setState(() {
    readIndex = i;
  });
  translatedText == null
      ? await flutterTts.speak(steps[i].toString())        
      : await flutterTts.speak(translatedText.toString());

}
```

Now when I use my for loop, I get the steps and index like this :

```
I/flutter (25591): 0
I/flutter (25591): Heat a large skillet over medium heat; add rice and lentils. Cook and stir until toasted and fragrant, 3 to 4 minutes. Rinse.
I/flutter (25591): 1
I/flutter (25591): Place rice-lentil mixture, 1 tablespoon ghee, and salt in a rice cooker or pressure cooker; add water. Cook according to manufacturer's instructions until rice and lentils are tender and the consistency of a paste, 20 to 25 minutes. Stir and mash into a fine paste.
D/TTS     (25591): Utterance ID has been stopped: 98bd4603-7594-481c-803a-e2007ed0cf13. Interrupted: true
I/flutter (25591): 2
I/flutter (25591): Heat 1 tablespoon ghee in a skillet over medium-high heat. Add black pepper and cumin seeds; cook until seeds start to pop, 2 to 3 minutes. Stir cumin mixture into rice-lentil mixture.
D/TTS     (25591): Utterance ID has been stopped: f9ca3808-3036-4d73-89e7-6a91e9227699. Interrupted: true
I/flutter (25591): 3
I/flutter (25591): Tear curry leaves roughly and stir into rice-lentil mixture; stir in ginger. Season with salt.
I/flutter (25591): 4
I/flutter (25591): Heat remaining 1 tablespoon ghee in a skillet over medium-high heat; cook and stir cashews until toasted and fragrant, 2 to 4 minutes. Garnish rice-lentil mixture with toasted cashews.
```

(the translatedText is also indexed via the readIndex).
Well now, the problem is that, using flutter_tts in for loop., the index 0,1,2,3 are not red and it directly reads only the last iteration. (What I mean is that, it detects every index(as you can see above), but speaks only the last iteration..(iteration))..
The other iterations are stopped. Check the output below :

```
D/TTS     (25591): Utterance ID has been stopped: 061aaa35-a1eb-48d5-a2a8-b275cdafb7bb. Interrupted: false
D/TTS     (25591): Utterance ID has been stopped: 8eb8131e-7ce6-4f0a-9908-00e90c91abf7. Interrupted: false
D/TTS     (25591): Utterance ID has been stopped: 061aaa35-a1eb-48d5-a2a8-b275cdafb7bb. Interrupted: false
D/TTS     (25591): Utterance ID has started: 1c9b2d9d-9b38-4e51-96e2-3aee1c857c33
```

As you can see the output, it says `Utterance ID has been stopped` for the first three indexes and starts playing only in the last index. `Utterance ID has started: 1c9b2d9d-9b38-4e51-96e2-3aee1c857c33`

Well, I could directly convert the steps list to string(via steps.toString()) and read the whole contents but,

why I am doing this using indexing is that, when a particular step is red, I want the particular step card to change its color (where I have included a ternary condition)

```
 ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            itemCount: steps.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return Card(
                                  color: index == readIndex? Colors.blue
                                      : null,
```

Like this :   https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCatN.jpg

Facing this weird error but the first time.. It seems to be an issue with flutter_tts package.

**Alternate Steps tried to change the color when the particular step is red :**

->
Here, I have converted steps list to string through steps.toString().

flutter_tts has a feature called setProgresshandler(text,start,end,word), where this word returns what word is being read by the tts.(i.e., eg Let the string be "1 cup of white rice".., when the flutter_tts reads "rice", it outputs/gives the word "rice"),
the start gives the start of the start index of the string, and the end gives the index at what the word is being red(for the above example "rice", end returns 4,)..
So using that, I got the word which was being red, but the issue was there was same words in multiple indexes of steps list, therefore, multiple cards were coloured blue(was blikking).

(You can see there's a word called Skillet in the 0th,2th and 4th index.. therefore this blue color is applied to all these)

Like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEj8L.jpg

So to solve this issue, I brought up this index==readIndex thingy.., and I'm struck up here....
Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a for loop, you should first set await flutterTts.awaitSpeakCompletion(true);
I should add this.
That's it, the issue was fixed..

Comment: Can you at least include a code snippet showing your answer to make the answer more understandable?